# How to set an item limit on localstorage items Javascript HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, storage, local

I am trying to set a limit of 6 items to localstorage and also retrieve the items back. So for example if a user types in data into an input box with id #gsc-i-id2 and clicks the .gsc-search-button-v2, the data gets stored in localstorage which all works fine but I want to limit this to the 6 most recent input's, in the code i've tried using .shift but i'm very new to localstorage and js and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. It does display only 6 items but doesn't shit the items up. any help would be very much appreciated.

```js
(function() {

    var propertiesList = document.getElementById('list');
    var myProperties;
    var obj;
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('Address')) {
      displayStorage();
    }
  
    // function to display localStorage contents on page load
    function displayStorage() {
      var data = "";
      myProperties = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Address'));
  
      // if localStorage array is not empty
      if (myProperties.length !== 0) {
  
        for (var i = 0; i < myProperties.length; i++) {
  
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          data += myProperties[i].address + " ";
          li.innerHTML = data;
          data = '';
          propertiesList.appendChild(li);
  
        }
      }
    }
    $("body").on('click', '.gsc-search-button-v2', function(index) {
      var address = document.getElementById('gsc-i-id2');
      obj = {};
      obj.address = address.value;
      myProperties = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Address')) || [];
      myProperties.push(obj);
      localStorage.setItem('Address', JSON.stringify(myProperties));
        addToPropertiesList();
    })
  
    function addToPropertiesList(e) {

      var len = myProperties.length - 1;
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var data = '';
      data += myProperties[len].address + " ";
      li.innerHTML = data;
      if(len > 5){
        myProperties.shift(li);
      } else{
      propertiesList.appendChild(li);
      }
    }
  
  }());
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" size="10" class="gsc-input" name="search" title="search" id="gsc-i-id2" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" style="width: 100%; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: -0.0625em 0px 0px; height: 1.25em; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); outline: none;">

<td class="gsc-search-button"><button class="gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2"><svg width="13" height="13" viewBox="0 0 13 13"><title>search</title><path d="m4.8495 7.8226c0.82666 0 1.5262-0.29146 2.0985-0.87438 0.57232-0.58292 0.86378-1.2877 0.87438-2.1144 0.010599-0.82666-0.28086-1.5262-0.87438-2.0985-0.59352-0.57232-1.293-0.86378-2.0985-0.87438-0.8055-0.010599-1.5103 0.28086-2.1144 0.87438-0.60414 0.59352-0.8956 1.293-0.87438 2.0985 0.021197 0.8055 0.31266 1.5103 0.87438 2.1144 0.56172 0.60414 1.2665 0.8956 2.1144 0.87438zm4.4695 0.2115 3.681 3.6819-1.259 1.284-3.6817-3.7 0.0019784-0.69479-0.090043-0.098846c-0.87973 0.76087-1.92 1.1413-3.1207 1.1413-1.3553 0-2.5025-0.46363-3.4417-1.3909s-1.4088-2.0686-1.4088-3.4239c0-1.3553 0.4696-2.4966 1.4088-3.4239 0.9392-0.92727 2.0864-1.3969 3.4417-1.4088 1.3553-0.011889 2.4906 0.45771 3.406 1.4088 0.9154 0.95107 1.379 2.0924 1.3909 3.4239 0 1.2126-0.38043 2.2588-1.1413 3.1385l0.098834 0.090049z"></path></svg></button></td>

<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you should separate the code for DOM manipulation and the code for interacting with localstorage. This will make the code more readable for those who look at your question!

Comment: Thank you, i added minimal html but i'm not sure exactly how to seperate it for DOM manipulation sorry

Comment: Look at my github repo for an example of keeping localstorage methods organized into each function. https://github.com/geniuskouta/local_storage_js/blob/master/index.html This will help you separate your local storage action from DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you want to only save 6 recent items on localstorage

Since you can't directly set rules on localstorage, I suggest my solution as to how you should save the data on localstorage in this case:

1. check the length of the data array after you add an item to the array
2. remove the first item of the array if the length of the array exceeds 6
3. save the array data on localstorage

I provide the snippet for the process above.

```
   // add code here for adding an item to the array

   if(exceedsPropertiesLengthLimit(myProperties)) {
       myProperties.shift();
   }

   // add code here for saving the array data on localstorage
    
   function exceedsPropertiesLengthLimit(properties) {
        let limitLength = 6;
        let exceedsLimit = false;

        if(properties.length > limitLength) {
            exceedsLimit = true;
        }
        return exceedsLimit;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your help with this, but I can't seem to figure out exactly where to place your code within mine to get it to work?

Comment: I believe it should be inserted into the line after `myProperties.push(obj)`, if that's where you add an item to the array. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Kouta, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I understood the problem. If you only want to print the latest 5 addresses, then you may try something like this:

```
if(len>5){
for(var j = len; j>= len - 5; j++){
.... // Write here what you want to do with the last five values
     }
}
```